# Getting nullpointer exception in loadUserByUsername method while validating login crendentials

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot web application in which I am trying to integrate Spring Security, the problem that I'm facing is getting a nullpointer exception in loadUserByUsername of UserDetailsService method. I have checked in my mysql database that given username exists, tried adding and removing BCrypt encoded password and plain text password, but still getting this error. I am posting the details below

Exception

```
2019-04-11 13:51:50.457[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m5856[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mw.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: null
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:123) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.amoksha.service.UserSecurityService.loadUserByUsername(UserSecurityService.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

1.SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;


// once defined, salt value should never be changed,,, should be as random as
// possible
private static final String SALT="JHBLGO&AJS70&";

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12, new SecureRandom(SALT.getBytes()));
}

/* Public URLS */
private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = { "/webjars/**", "/i18n/**", "/css/**", "js/**", "/images/**", "/",
        "/errors/**" };

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/").failureUrl("/loginerror").permitAll().and().logout()
            .permitAll();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userSecurityService);
    System.out.println();
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());//(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
    return provider;
}
```

}

2.UserSecurityService

```
@Service
public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService{

private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    return user;
}}
```

3.UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

4.User.java

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public User() {}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String username;

private String password;

@Column(unique = true)
private String email;

private boolean enabled;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
    userRoles.forEach(ur -> authorities.add(new Authority(ur.getRole().getName())));
    return authorities;
}

//Other getters and setter
//......
```

5.login.html(thymeleaf)

```
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">UserName</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
```

6. UserService
   public User createUser(User user, Set userRoles) {

   ```
   User localUser = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());

   if (localUser != null) {
       /*
        * LOG.
        * info("User with username {} and email {} already exist. Nothing will be done. "
        * , user.getUsername(), user.getEmail());
        */
   } else {

       String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
       user.setPassword(encryptedPassword);

       for (UserRole ur : userRoles) {
           roleRepository.save(ur.getRole());
       }

       user.getUserRoles().addAll(userRoles);

       localUser = userRepository.save(user);

   }

   return localUser;
   ```

   }

7.Creating user method:

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    User user = new User();

    user.setUsername("test");
    user.setEmail("test@test.com");
    user.setPassword("{bcrypt}test");
    user.setEnabled(true);
    Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<>();
    roles.add(new UserRole(user, new Role(RolesEnum.BASIC)));
    userRep.createUser(user, roles);

}
```

How to remove/debug this exception?

Comment: can u post the exception please.. @Phoenix

Comment: Added the stacktrace, please have a look

Comment: I've also added code by which i'm creating user

Comment: The error is your custom `UserSecurityService` you MUST throw an exception if the user is not found. You aren't and always return, hence when a non-existing user is detected you `return null`. With not throwing an exception you are breaking the `UserDetailsService` contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are missing the `@Autowired` on the `UserRepository` in the `UserSecurityService`. Hence nothing will be injected.

Second your implementation of the `UserSecurityService` is flawed as it breaks the contract for `UserDetailsService`. When no user can be found you MUST throw an `UsernameNotFoundException`.

So your full implementation should look something like this.

```
@Service
public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService{

  private final UserRepository userRepository;

  public UserSecurityService(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository=userRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found for "+ username + ".");
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

I prefer constructor injection over field injection hence the constructor with the `UserRepository` and with newer versions of Spring (4.3 or greater) you don't need an `@Autowired` on a single constructor.